# Why would the UK suddenly grant full citizenship to Hongkongers?

Tags: politics

I'm writing a fictional immigration guide for all Hongkongers with [the British National (Overseas) ("BN(O)") passport](https://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/politics/article/2157756/what-british-national-overseas-passport-and-what-holder), who now have full UK citizenship and are deciding whether to move to the UK.   What would convince the UK to grant full UK citizenship to Hongkongers with the British National (Overseas) passport?

Assume

- the world as it is now on Oct. 17 2019.
- no military conflicts or wars between UK and China.
- HK is still part of China.
- HK protestors don't seize any more control, power, money, weapons.

  1. [This news article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/sep/02/hong-kong-protests-calls-grow-to-give-citizens-right-to-live-and-work-in-uk) implies that few MPs support granting full citizenship to BN(O)s.

  > Last month Tom Tugendhat, chair of the Commons foreign affairs committee, [said that Britain should grant Hong Kong citizens with BN(O) passports](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/aug/13/uk-british-nationality-hong-kong-citizens-tom-tugendhat) full UK nationality. He told the FT that “a few” cabinet ministers were supportive of the decision.

  2. Previous efforts have all failed.

  > Chris Patten, the last governor of Hong Kong before the handover, unsuccessfully urged the UK to [give the right of abode](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk-should-let-in-33-million-from-hong-kong-says-patten-1602582.html) to all those holding British Dependent Territories passports.
  >
  > The late Lord Ashdown, who as Liberal Democrat leader campaigned on the issue, said last year that Britain was “urgently in need of some soul-searching enquiry about our neglect of duty towards our former colonial subjects” which should include considering the rights of BN(O) in Hong Kong.
  >
  > Last year, declassified files revealed that Britain even pressured Portugal repeatedly not to grant rights to citizens of Macau before it handed the region back to [China](https://www.theguardian.com/world/china), fearing that it would increase the pressure to grant Hong Kong similar rights.
  >
  > Lisbon granted passports, [with full citizenship rights](https://www.scmp.com/news/hong-kong/politics/article/2156385/britains-disgraceful-pre-handover-efforts-deny-nationality), to anyone born before late 1981 and allowed Portuguese nationality to be passed to their children.

  3. Some UKers are anti-immigration, and peradventure racist.
  4. Granting full citizenship will mar UK's relationship and trade with China, which the UK probably won't jeopardize.  [‘Pro-China’ Boris Johnson [is] ‘enthusiastic’ about belt and road plan](https://sg.news.yahoo.com/pro-china-boris-johnson-enthusiastic-065100165.html):

  > Boris Johnson, Britain’s prime minister-designate, said his government would be very “pro-China”, in an interview with a Hong Kong-based Chinese-language broadcaster shortly before he was chosen to succeed Theresa May on Tuesday.

Comment: This seems like it's a hypothetical question about our current right-now world rather than what a question about building a hypothetical world, which is normally our scope.

Comment: This is almost more suited to Politics SE than it is here. While an interesting sentiment and used in a work of fiction (fake immigration guide) I don't see a question on how to actually build a world.

Comment: @ITAlex If this one small change is being used in a work of fiction then this constitutes its fictional world. Devising a way of how to achieve it, is worldbuilding.